# Trouble with retrieving data with prepared statement in DAO

Tags: java, jdbc

```
public class StudentDAO extends ConnectorDAO {

    private List<StudentBean> studentList = new LinkedList<>();
    private StudentBean studentBean;

    public List<StudentBean> retrieveStudents() {

        Connection connection;

        try {
            String myQuery = "SELECT ?, ?, ? FROM Students";
            connection = getConnection() // getConnection() comes from superclass

            PreparedStatement preparedstatement = connection.prepareStatement(myQuery);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "firstname");
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "lastname");
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "studentID");

            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                studentBean = new StudentBean();
                studentBean.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("firstname"));
                studentBean.setLastName(resultSet.getString("lastname"));
                studentBean.setID(resultSet.getInt("studentID"));
                studentList.add(studentBean);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Error handling stuff
        } finally {
            // close connection, resultset and preparedstatement
        }

    } 
}
```

An error shows in my eclipse. On the line where I set the studentBean's ID. The data type of the studentID in my database is of Int. I'm not sure how to retrieve it though. Can anyone help me? It works when I use a Statement object when I query with the parameters used in the prepared statement.

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: "java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'studentID'"

Comment: @Nate Okay, so if the datatype in the db is int, can you 1) Put that error message in the question body text, and 2) Give us an example row that'd be returned by the query but still croak on that line? Without that, it's harder to figure out what might be wrong without completely guessing

Answer (score 2):

Your code for building the query is incorrect:

```
        String myQuery = "SELECT ?, ?, ? FROM Students";
        connection = getConnection() // getConnection() comes from superclass

        PreparedStatement preparedstatement = connection.prepareStatement(myQuery);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, "firstname");
        preparedStatement.setString(2, "lastname");
        preparedStatement.setString(3, "studentID");
```

Is not possible:
A query string is formatted like this (example):

```
String myQuery = "SELECT firstname, lastname, studentID FROM Students WHERE studentID=?";
```

The parameters are only to be used on variables not on column names, table names etc.

So once you have code like that you could query on a `studentID` (not your goal but just for the example):

```
preparedStatement.setInt(1, someStudentID);
```

Which would be send with the `preparedStatement` to the DBMS in which then the DBMS replaces the `?` with the value of `someStudentID`.

Comment: Does this mean that I can only use the question marks after the WHERE keyword?

Comment: @Nate You can use them anywhere a literal (string, number, ...) can be used. Used in the `SELECT` clause like you have, it means that all returned rows will have the given value in that column, and since the column is unnamed, it can only be retrieved by index, e.g. `rs.getString(1)`. You can name it by specifying `SELECT ? AS foo, ? AS bar FROM Students`, in which case you could retrieve using `rs.getString("foo")`.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `setString` (or `setInt` or any other `setXXX` in `PreparedStatement`), is "replace the corresponding question mark with the given value, appropriately typed". So this code:

```
String myQuery = "SELECT ?, ?, ? FROM Students";
connection = getConnection() // getConnection() comes from superclass

PreparedStatement preparedstatement = connection.prepareStatement(myQuery);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "firstname");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "lastname");
preparedStatement.setString(3, "studentID");
```

Effectively creates the following query:

```
SELECT 'firstname', 'lastname', 'studentID' FROM Students
```

Now, this tells it to select three literal strings from the table. If you ran this query in an SQL command line utility or something similar, you'd find that the result is

```
firstname | lastname | studentID
firstname | lastname | studentID
firstname | lastname | studentID
firstname | lastname | studentID
...
```

Instead of what you expected. Anything set by `setString` is interpreted as a literal string - as if it includes single quotes.

So question marks are used for setting values in the statement, that would be literal values if you were typing the statement in a command line utility.

So what your result set has is rows upon rows containing the three strings `firstname`, `lastname` and `studentID`.

Now, in the next bit of code:

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
    studentBean = new StudentBean();
    studentBean.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("firstname"));
    studentBean.setLastName(resultSet.getString("lastname"));
    studentBean.setID(resultSet.getInt("studentID"));
    studentList.add(studentBean);
}
```

in many database systems, you wouldn't even be able to use `getString("firstname")` because the returned column name from a query for literals is arbitrary. But I suppose your database system actually gives the return column the same name as the literal value. So you are able to retrieve `firstname` and `lastname` (But their content is not the student name! It's the literal strings `"firstname"` and `"lastname"`), because you are using `getString`.

But you run out of luck when you try to use `getInt`. Since you queried for literal strings, you are getting back three strings. The third column is not an integer but the literal string `"studentID"`. This is where you hit the error.

So you should change your query to

```
"SELECT firstname, lastname, studentID FROM Students"
```

Which means you don't necessarily need a prepared statement in this case, but it doesn't hurt either.

---

Where can you use the question marks, then?

Anywhere you need a literal value in your query. For example, if you want to know the difference between a person's year of birth and a given year, you could write:

```
SELECT year_of_birth - ? FROM people
```

And then use `setInt(1,1969)` or `setInt(1,2001)` to make the query become:

```
SELECT year_of_birth - 1969 FROM people
```

and

```
SELECT year_of_birth - 2001 FROM people
```

Respectively. In prepared statements, the actual names of database objects such as columns and tables, which are not literals, cannot be replaced with a question mark. They are part of the query plan itself.

Comment: Noted, this seems to make a lot of sense.